# TypeError: this.setState is not a function, inside Redux Actions file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm attempting to reconfigure a PixaBay clone application to Redux. The application retrieves photos as the user types a search text. However, it breaks as soon as I type inside the input. 
From what I've researched, you can only call setState in a class so I gave fetchPhotos an arrow function, but that didn't work. I also tried to `.bind(this)`, but that gave me a parsing error. Could someone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here are the following errors, along with my code.

ERRORS

```
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
fetchPhotos
src/actions/actions.js:10
   7 | 
   8 | export function fetchPhotos(e) {
   9 |   const url = `${ROOT_URL}/?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchText}&image_type=photo`;
> 10 |   const request = this.setState({searchText: e.target.value}, () => {
  11 |     axios.get(url)
  12 |     .then(response => {
  13 |       this.setState({images: response.data.hits});

fetchPhotos
    node_modules/redux/es/redux.js:475
    Search._this.FetchPhotosHandler [as onChange]
    src/components/search/Search.js:11
       8 | class Search extends Component {
       9 | 
      10 |   FetchPhotosHandler = (e) => {
    > 11 |     this.props.fetchPhotos(e);
      12 |   }
      13 | 
      14 |   render() {
```

SEARCH CONTAINER

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchPhotos } from '../../actions/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import ImageResults from '../imageResults/ImageResults';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    images: []
  }

  FetchPhotosHandler = (e) => {
    this.props.fetchPhotos(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField 
        name="searchText"
        value={this.props.searchText}
        onChange={this.FetchPhotosHandler}
        floatingLabelText="Search for photos"
        fullWidth={true} />
        <br />
        <ImageResults images={this.props.images} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchPhotos, dispatch});
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

ACTION

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_PHOTOS = 'FETCH_PHOTOS';

const ROOT_URL = 'https://pixabay.com/api';
const API_KEY = '10264275-868d83de96a4d0c47db26f9e0';
const searchText = '';

export function fetchPhotos(e) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchText}&image_type=photo`;
  const request = this.setState({searchText: e.target.value}, () => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({images: response.data.hits});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_PHOTOS,
    payload: request 
  };
}
```

REDUCER

```
import { FETCH_PHOTOS } from '../actions/actions';

 const initialState = {
   searchText: '',
   images: []
 }


const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_PHOTOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        images: action.data.hits
      };
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: You simply shouldn&amp;#39;t be calling setState in a Redux action. setState is for managing local state of a `React.Component`. The point of the action is to dispatch a type/payload to a reducer with which you update store state. That state is mapped to props in your component. You can use middleware to dispatch actions from within then/catch of your API call. Look at minimum at something like redux-thunk. Also  are you planning to map your store state to props (first argument of connect) to retrieve the values from the store?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @AlexanderStaroselsky. I'm going to rethink this over.

Comment: `setState` inside of actions. That's a first for me. Stop doing that. setState() schedules an update to a COMPONENT'S state object.
Your code needs major refactoring. You don't even have a state in that file, so what are you actually setting? I suggest visiting the official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do) ... happy hacking ;)

Comment: Appreciate it! @Bigga_HD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid attempting to use `setState()` in your action as it goes against Redux entirely. `setState()` is meant for managing the **local** of a `React.Component`. As you are attempting to utilize Redux, you should instead dispatch actions from your actions creators that update the store via your reducers and finally mapping store values to your component's props via `connect()`. Below is an example of your code restructured similar to the [Async](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) Redux example.

Instead of attempting to call `setState()` in the action, instead an action is dispatched containing the image payload. The `Search` component utilizes [mapStateToProps](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) (1st argument of connect()) to map store properties such the images array to the component's props. These props are used to render a list of data. This completely eliminates the need to have an `images` local state property on `Search` as values are being retrieved from the store as changes happen via actions/reducers. This example uses [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware to handle async actions, but there are plenty of other options out there that you could consider.

store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const middleware = [ thunk ];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default store;
```

actions:

```
export const FETCH_PHOTOS = 'FETCH_PHOTOS';
export const RECEIVE_PHOTOS = 'RECEIVE_PHOTOS';

// fake data
const testPhotos = [
  { id: 1, src: 'https://placehold.it/250' },
  { id: 2, src: 'https://placehold.it/250' }
];

// fake API call as promise
const getTestPhotos = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(testPhotos);
    }, 500);
  });
}

const fetchPhotos = (searchText) => ({
  type: FETCH_PHOTOS
});

const receivePhotos = (photos) => ({
  type: RECEIVE_PHOTOS,
  data: {
    hits: photos
  }
});

export const searchPhotos = (searchText) => dispatch => {
  // dispatch an action to handle loading/waiting for API response
  dispatch(fetchPhotos(searchText));

  // dispatch another action with payload within then()
  return getTestPhotos()
    .then(photos => dispatch(receivePhotos(photos)));
}
```

reducer:

```
import { FETCH_PHOTOS, RECEIVE_PHOTOS } from '../actions';

 const initialState = {
   loading: false,
   searchText: '',
   images: []
 }

const photos = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_PHOTOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case RECEIVE_PHOTOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        images: action.data.hits
      };
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}

export default photos;
```

Search:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { searchPhotos } from './actions';

class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      searchText: ''
    };

    this.fetchPhotosHandler = this.fetchPhotosHandler.bind(this);
  }

  fetchPhotosHandler(e) {
    const { value: searchText } = e.target;

    this.setState({ ...this.state, searchText }, () => {
      this.props.dispatch(searchPhotos(e));
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, images } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="search">Search:</label>
          <input name="search" id="search" type="text" value={this.state.searchText} onChange={this.fetchPhotosHandler} />
        </div>

        {loading ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
            <ul>
              {images.map(image => <li key={image.id}>{image.src}</li>)}
            </ul>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ photos: { loading, images } }) => ({ loading, images });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Search);
```

I've created an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7mdrfy) to show this functionality in action at a basic level.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind component class instance to your action and it should work.

```
FetchPhotosHandler = (e) => {
    this.props.fetchPhotos.bind(this)(e);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this has given me a TypeError: dispatch is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Since you have fetchPhotos exported from different module and in order to do setState there you need to pass this context to fetchPhotos as a param and use the param to do setState. That's how this context will be available

Pass this to fetchPhotos as a param

```
FetchPhotosHandler = (e) => {
    this.props.fetchPhotos(e, this);
  }
```

And here access this and do seState

```
export function fetchPhotos(e, this) {
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}/?key=${API_KEY}&q=${searchText}&image_type=photo`;
  const request = this.setState({searchText: e.target.value}, () => {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({images: response.data.hits});
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  });

  return {
    type: FETCH_PHOTOS,
    payload: request 
  };
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this gave me a Parsing error: Unexpected token

Comment: Sure thing, here you go. There are 3 total. 
••• `Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/KennPangilinan/DEV/ReactJS/flickr/src/actions/actions.js: Unexpected token`

••• `./src/actions/actions.js
  Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token` `index.js:1455 ./src/actions/actions.js
SyntaxError: /Users/KennPangilinan/DEV/ReactJS/flickr/src/actions/actions.js: Unexpected token`

••• `index.js:1455 ./src/actions/actions.js
  Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token`